# my jQuery code no longer fit to jQuery 1.9 .on. Someone tell me what should I do now?

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle

```
$(".p-list > ul > li").click(function () {

    if ($(this).children('.sub-parts').length > 0) {

        if (!$(this).hasClass('open')) {
            $(this).addClass('open');
            $(this).find('.sub-parts').fadeIn('normal');
        }
    }
});


$(document.body).on('click', ".p-list .open-tl", function () {
    if ($(this).parent('.open').length > 0) {
        $open = $(this).parent('.open');
        $($open).find('.sub-parts').hide();
        $($open).removeClass('open');
    }
});
```

I have this code that hide the div on click and show them when they click on open'tab .open-tl.

The problem is second code is executd after Fadein code when I don't want to run second code.

please someone check http://jsfiddle.net/vNfeD/

Comment: Is there a reason you need 1.9 feature set, if you can't re factor code to work on 1.9 it seems odd that you'd need 1.9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$open = $(this).parent('.open');
$($open).find('.sub-parts').hide();
$($open).removeClass('open');
```

must be

```
$open = $(this).parent('.open');
$open.find('.sub-parts').hide();
$open.removeClass('open');
```

and you can reduct it

```
$(this).parent('.open').removeClass('open').find('.sub-parts').hide();
```

the parent if can be removed, if object is empty jquery will do nothing

```
if ($(this).parent('.open').length > 0) { // remove that
```

for not allow second code execution when child are hiden, add a event.stopPropagation(); just when there is not .open and when there is subs, check the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/r043v/vNfeD/5/

Comment: Thanks for your help, I want to hide li on the click on .open-tl and show them in the li's click. Your code is still not have do that thing.

Comment: if work fine for me when i click on the 6th li, isn't the good thing ?